# How to populate a text field after fetching in a database once drop down item is selected

Tags: php

This is my code that prints the last name of the person owning the ID_no which is in a drop down option. What I want is to output it in a text box so once the id_no is selected it will automatically fill the field:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "auth";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "auth");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id_no,fn,sn,mn from employee ORDER BY id_no asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

<select name='id_no' onchange="changeSelect(this.value)">
   <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>

 <option value="<?php echo($row['sn']);  ?>"   > 

       <?php echo($row['id_no']); ?> 

   </option> 
   <?php }  ?> 

</select>

<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
function changeSelect(value)
{
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value
}
</script>
```

---

- My question is, where will I put the `<input type="text">` thingy?

Comment: Ok, and the question is? Errors, if any? Checking for them?

Comment: there were no errors

Comment: so could you update your question with full html generated?
or provide a link to your page?

Comment: its not online :(( just correct me where will I put this : <input type=text name=name size=50 required> ? for it to be printed inside the text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo"<input type=text name=fullname size=50  value=$row[sn],$row[fn],$row[mn] required>";
```

yes i did it:)